# RouterStatusEntryV3 doesn't have members it should have...?

Tags: exit-relays, error, stem

AttributeError: 'RouterStatusEntryV3' object has no attribute 'measured'

measured (int) -- bandwidth measured to be available by the relay, this is a unit-less heuristic generated by the Bandwidth authoritites to weight relay selection
(https://stem.torproject.org/api/descriptor/router_status_entry.html#stem.descriptor.router_status_entry.RouterStatusEntry)

What's going on?

Edit:

Relevant code:

```
print TOR_CONTROLLER.get_network_status('e9c8154418544764619d2ccd0596b355d7dff236').measured
```

output:

```
******>python tor.py
Jun 25 12:29:25.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 0%: Starting
Jun 25 12:29:36.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 80%: Connecting to the Tor network
Jun 25 12:29:37.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 85%: Finishing handshake with first hop
Jun 25 12:29:38.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 90%: Establishing a Tor circuit
Jun 25 12:29:38.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 100%: Done
>authenticating...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tor.py", line 271, in <module>
    print     TOR_CONTROLLER.get_network_status('e9c8154418544764619d2ccd0596b355d7d
ff236').measured
      File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\stem\descriptor\__init__.py", line 611, in
 __getattr__
    return super(Descriptor, self).__getattribute__(name)
AttributeError: 'RouterStatusEntryV3' object has no attribute 'measured'
```

It prints the bandwidth attribute just fine, also the address attribute.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit? right now it is unclear what you're asking.

Comment: I'm trying to get measured bandwidth which the object SHOULD contain. Yet it doesn't even have the member much less the desired information. So what am I doing wrong? Because it seems like the object description and implementation do not match.

Comment: pip installs outddated 1.4.0 version that does not contain this attribute.

Answer (score 1):

Please [file a ticket](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/wiki/doc/stem/bugs) with code and the descriptor that reproduces this. You're right that the RouterStatusEntryV3 class has a measured attribute. First guess is that you might have a RouterStatusEntryV2 instance instead.

Comment: Made an edit to my question. before submitting a ticket I would like to know if I'm doing everything correctly.